# Edit File Explorer in VS Code using their API

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I want to edit the file explorer in VS Code using their API. I see that having an initiated git repository changes the color of the file names and adds some stuff next to each file name, so that means I also can change it, right?

This is the file explorer that I mean:

[image: File Explorer]

Comment: if you want to lean how to use part of an API, you can normally look at the actual documentation. i know it sucks as a beginner, since there's a lot of reading, but this is the best way to learn how to do something. here is the docs for vscode FS provider: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystemProvider

Comment: @oriraisfeld I already looked at it and I couldn't find anything. The only thing I found is creating a Tree View, but nothing about editing the File Explorer.

Comment: With a `FileDecorationProvider` you can change the Explorer's colors and badges for any files you choose.